# Regex help targeting %2526_ga%253d and write it out as &_ga= using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need help with regex to convert this entire string `%2526_ga%253d` exactly into `&_ga=`

When I test it here http://regexpal.com/ I enter `%[A-Z0-9]{4}` into the top field

Then I enter `%253ftestingst%253dmember%2526_ga%253d1.123760009` into the bottom field.

It highlights the `%2526` nicely however I need help being sure it only targets `%2526_ga%253d` exactly.

Then, how does one convert it to write `&_ga=` using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex here. Just call `decodeURIComponent` twice:

```
var s = '%2526_ga%253d'

var r = decodeURIComponent ( decodeURIComponent(s) );
//=> &_ga=
```

Comment: I understand now. var url = '%2526_ga%253d';var decodeme = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(url));alert(decodeme);